# Arrange different "salt" GUI components in different positions for a whole big GUI?

Tags: user-interface, org-mode, salt, plantuml

I am trying to use PlantUML "salt" to design a whole big GUI
It's easy to generate different GUI components by salt, but how to arrange them into different position in a whole GUI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, we can use {}|{} to arrange the different block horizontally, and use {}{} to arrange them vertically...

Comment: Like the question this answer is also lacking an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
!function _f7()
{
    <b>adding tabs vertically
    {+

      {/
          <b>General
          Fullscreen
          Behavior
          Saving
      }|
      ' it is important to align | just after the }
      ' this would align the 2 salt block side by side
      ' otherwise remove the | you will get vertical alignment
      {
         { Open image in: | ^Smart Mode^ }
         [X] Smooth images when zoomed
         [X] Confirm image deletion
         [ ] Show hidden images
         [Close]
      }
 }
}
!endfunction
```